# UIScrollview: What is setting the contentSize back to 0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView`, and in `viewDidAppear` I set the `contentSize`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGSize scrollContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 9200);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = scrollContentSize;
}
```

This code is definitely running.

However, the view doesn't scroll. I wired up a button to log the `contentSize`, and it returns 0,0. If I get the button to set `contentSize` again it works fine.

I'm not referencing `scrollView` anywhere else in my code, what could be setting the `contentSize` back to 0, and is there any way I can stop it from doing so, or run my setup later in the process of setting up the view?

Comment: I have temporarily fixed this by using `[self performSelector:@selector(setScroll) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];` in `viewDidAppear`. It's a pretty awful hack though, so I'd rather not do it.

Comment: UIScrollView is inside the rootview? or rootview is UIScrollView? Are u using Autolayout or not?

Comment: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com It is inside the rootview. I think I'm using Autolayout (I haven't turned it on or off, it's set to whatever the default is).

Comment: if you used the Autolayout then you have to make constraints for subviews in it. then Autolayout will calculate its content size automatically.

Comment: UIScrollView's initial setup depends on if you are using autolayout a lot. I suggest you post more informatiion about your settings about scrollView and its contentView in storyboard and complete setup of your scrollView in source code.

Answer (score 0):

if you used the Autolayout then you have to make constraints for subviews in it. Then Autolayout will calculate its content size automatically.

**But when I set contentsize through button action it works? How?**

When the view relayout the scrollview again it will be calculated based on the constraints. So it won't work when u rotate the device/relayout the view.

**I don't want to use the autolayout?Now what?**

Then you are good to set contentsize.

One more thing, it is best practice to call super implementation on few lifecyle methods.
so do it so.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     // Your code here
 }
```

[Here is the Good starting point](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013309)

[Excellent tutorial](http://blog.surecase.eu/working-with-uiscrollview-in-storyboard-using-autolayout/)